# How to ignore newlines in TextField?

Tags: flutter, textfield

Simple question that I'm not finding an answer to--I have a TextField that's multi-line but I don't want to allow newlines in the text. E.g., if the user is typing and hits [Enter], I don't want a newline to register in the TextField. How do I do that?

I tried catching it in the onChanged event, but got weird rendering results:

```
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.endsWith('\n')) {
          _textController.text = value.trim();
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try using `BlacklistingTextInputFormatter` in `inputFormatters`.

```
inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(new RegExp(r"\n"))
],
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use following parameters:

```
TextField(keyboardType: TextInputType.text, maxLines: 3,);
```